# Retrieving values from Json file

Tags: jquery, json

I have Json file with below information.

```
successalert({
"School_name": "Convent",
"Class":"12th"
});
```

Here "successalert" returning function name.I am calling this file from jquery.This is running but I want to fetch data "convent" and "12th" in my JavaScript.

when i am writing code like

```
function successalert(data){

       for(var n in data)

        alert(n.method+"");

   }
```

This is giving "undefined" result in alert box.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the parseJSON method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the issue? If he has the JSON object then obj.School_name and obj.Class will contain the data he wants.

Answer (score 0):

In your current for loop, the `n` variable is a string representing the keys "School_name" and "Class". You are trying to access a non-existent property named `method` on that string. That's why you're getting `undefined`.

You can access the values you're looking for using the following example.

```
function successalert(data){
  for(var n in data) {
    alert(data[n]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function successalert(data){
         for(var n in data)
            alert(data[n]);
    }

n is the property, data[n] is the value